# Solving equations with change of variables is not working?

Tags: equation-solving, syntax, expression-construction

I want to express it in the form

$$\text{expr=}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}C_1\exp\left(-t^2\right)f(t)dt$$, i.e., the integrand is a bounded smooth function $f(t)$ times $\exp(-t^2)$ and the domain of integration is the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

Define the integrand with the measure as

```
integrand = c*Exp[-m*x^2/ω^m]*1/(Sqrt[2*π]*λ*ω)*Exp[-(Log[B] - μ)^2/(2*λ^2)] Dt[B, Constants -> {λ, m, x, μ, ω}];
```

where we use `Dt[t]` to represent the measure, which we will transform using the substitution:

```
subs = Assuming[{μ > 0, λ > 0, B > 0, t ∈ Reals}, First@Solve[t == (Log[B] - μ)/(Sqrt[2] λ), B, Reals]]
(* {B -> E^((2 t λ + Sqrt[2] μ)/Sqrt[2])} *)
```

The transformation is done via

```
transformedIntegrand = integrand /. subs /. Log[Exp[x_]] :> x // Simplify
(* (c E^(-t^2 + Sqrt[2] t λ + μ - m x^2 ω^-m) Dt[t, Constants -> {m, x, λ, μ, ω}])/(Sqrt[π] ω) *)
```

where we have simplified the expression by hand to some extent.

Finally, we integrate:

```
Integrate[transformedIntegrand /. HoldPattern[Dt[a__]] :> 1, {t, -∞, ∞}]
(* (c E^(λ^2/2 + μ - m x^2 ω^-m))/ω *)
```

(We have to set the measure back to `1`, because obviously in *Mathematica* you don't specify the measure explicitly.)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Sorry, I mistype my MMA code...Please check your answer...$B$ in fact should be $\omega$. There is no $B$ in the expression..